# Server 2012 R2 Hyper-V VM losing connection when downloading unless logged into host OS

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop, hyper-v

I'm having a really strange issue with my home file server which currently runs Windows Server 2012 R2.

I've created a Hyper-V VM which works as intended, however when I start downloading on that VM the connection constantly drops (Mbps download goes to 0 and builds up again, and i lose RDP connection to that VM. This repeats indefinitely)

Here's the weird thing, when I RDP into the host OS, the VM will stop dropping the connection.

I initially thought this was a Power Management issue and disabled "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"for my Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller, however it did not help. The motherboard is a Gigabyte GA-H61M-S2PV.

The connection drops only occur on the VM, when downloading on the host os, the connection does not drop.

I'd really appreciate some input, i've spent the past 2 days figuring this out to no avail.

Comment: Are you able to check whether your home files server (not the virtual machine under it) is running out of free memory?  Is so, does it?

Answer (score 1):

The VM has plenty of dynamically allocated RAM. I've actually fixed the issue now - the problem was with the Realtek driver that was initially installed by the OS, I even visited the motherboard website to check if a newer one was available which is what dissuaded me from checking if it was a driver issue. If anyone else ever has this problem, make sure that you visit the realtek website and download the latest version for your appropriate OS as the motherboard manufacturer may not update it on their website.